# JCraft : SCP using private key without password

Tags: java, key-pair

I was trying to scp using key-pair between 2 linux server. I was trying to follow http://sthen.blogspot.in/2008/03/sftp-i-java-with-jsch-using-private-key.html

I am able to scp file between linux server but when I execute code I am getting error com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: UnknownHostKey. any idea what I am doing wrong.

Process : I have genrated passpharase free RSA key on client and copy public key on destination. now trying to scp file from client to destination using JCraft Librabry

I am using jar latest jar X.51

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your client simply have no know host key from the server side. There are two things that can be done: Either you tell JSch not to check host key at all or supply a valid key.

### Not checking HostKeys

In this case you have to supply a configuration with option `StrictHostKeyChecking` set to `no`:

```
...
JSch jsch = new JSch();
Session session = jsch.getSession(user, host, port);
Hashtable<String, String> config = new Hashtable<String, String>();
config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
session.setConfig(config);
session.connect();
...
```

### Supply HostKeys

In this case you supply a file with your host keys. The file is a standard OpenSSH known hosts key file and can be created and updated with the standard `ssh` command on Linux or cygwin.

```
...
JSch jsch = new JSch();
jsch.setKnownHosts(knownHostsFilename);
Session session = jsch.getSession(user, host, port);
Hashtable<String, String> config = new Hashtable<String, String>();
config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "yes");
session.setConfig(config);
session.connect();
...
```

My personal advice is to use the second way, as known host keys are an additional security feature of ssh you shouldn't abandon if not necessary.

PS: You shouldn't use only docs that are over 6 years old.

Comment: Thanks blafasel for your quick response. So If I am trying to scp from server A to B then A must contain detail for B in its know_host file and this file of server A need to configure in JCraft.setKnownHosts(filename);